# Incorrect evaluation of an indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong in this integration. The problem starts as: $$\int \sin^{2}{x}\cos^{7}{x} \, dx$$ My work is as follows: $\int \sin^{2}{x}\cos^{7}{x} \, dx = \int \sin^{2}{x}\cos^{6}{x}\cos{x} \, dx =
\int \sin^{2}{x}(1-\sin^{6}{x})\cos{x} \, dx = \int (\sin^{2}{x}-\sin^{8}{x}) \cos{x}$ 
 I let u = $\sin{x}$ and du = $\cos{x} dx$ 
So the integral now looks like:

$\int u^{2} - u^{8} du = u^{3}/3 - u^{9} /9 = $

$$ \sin^{3}{x} /3 - \sin^{9}{x} /9 $$

The practice exam does not have this listed as the correct answer, could someone please point out any mistakes. My apologies for any incorrect formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\cos^6 x = (1 - \sin^2 x)^3$. Don't make the mistake of thinking $(a-b)^3 = a^3 - b^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $(a-b)^3=a^3-b^3-3ab(a-b)=a^3-b^3-3a^2b+3ab^2$

$$\int \sin^2x\cos^7x\ dx=\int \sin^2x\cos^6x\cos x\ dx=\int \sin^2x(\cos^2x)^3\cos x\ dx$$
$$=\int \sin^2x(1-\sin^2x)^3\cos x\ dx$$
$$=\int \sin^2x(1-\sin^6x-3\sin^2x+3\sin^4x)\cos x\ dx$$
$$=\int (\sin^2x-\sin^8x-3\sin^4x+3\sin^6x)\cos x\ dx$$
let $\sin x=u\implies \cos x\ dx=du$
$$=\int (u^2-u^8-3u^4+3u^6)du$$
$$=\frac{u^3}{3}-\frac{u^9}{9}-3\frac{u^5}{5}+3\frac{u^7}{7}+C$$
$$=\frac{\sin^3x}{3}-\frac{\sin^9x}{9}-3\frac{\sin^5x}{5}+3\frac{\sin^7x}{7}+C$$